# Problem with quoting in shell script psql

Tags: postgresql, shell, scripting, quoting

I'm trying to use the following in a shell (/bin/sh) script but I keep getting errors:

```
su postgres -c "/usr/bin/psql -c \'CREATE ROLE user WITH SUPERUSER LOGIN PASSWORD \'$password;"
```

It seems that something with the quoting is wrong, but I can't find what is it. I should pass the variable `$password` and the command as postgres user. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are not even matched. You can escape double quotes within double quotes, and there is no need to escape single quotes.

```sh
su postgres -c "/usr/bin/psql -c \"CREATE ROLE username WITH SUPERUSER LOGIN PASSWORD '$password';\""
```

Note that `user` is not a valid name in SQL.